# Assumption of three points in the complement of the domain

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-dynamics

> Let $D$ be a subdomain of the complex sphere and suppose $D^c$ has at least three points.  Let $f$ be an analytic function which maps $D$ into itself and suppose that $f$ has an attracting fixed point $z_0$ in $D$.  Show that the iterates $f^n$ converge locally uniformly to $z_0$ in $D$.

This problem, along with Montel's theorem and a few other related theorems, all have this assumption of the three points in the complement.

Are the three points in the complement necessary to show convergence on $D$, and then additional steps are needed to show convergence to $z_0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition is there to ensure that $D$ is hyperbolic. If it is not satisfied, then $D$ is either the whole sphere, the plane, or a punctured plane (which is isomorphic to the cylinder $\mathbb C / \mathbb Z$). In each case there are holomorphic self-maps of $D$ for which the property fails.

For example, you can take $f(z)=z^2$, for which $z=0$ is attracting. The map $f$ is a self-map of $D$ if $D$ is either the plane or the sphere, but in both cases there are points in $D$ that are not attracted to zero (for instance, $z=1$).

Without knowing that $D$ is hyperbolic, you can only hope to obtain local results for the dynamics of $f$ near $z_0$ (namely that there is a neighborhood of $z_0$ of points attracted to $z_0$). However if $D$ is hyperbolic and $f: D \to D$ is a holomorphic map with an attracting fixed point, a general version of Schwartz's lemma tells you that $f$ is strictly contracting for the hyperbolic metric, and then it's just Banach's fixed point theorem.

Comment: In this case of the problem I stated, does knowing that there are at least three points in the complement allow me to conclude that the family of iterates are normal?

Comment: Yes, you can also use Montel's theorem. (in its proof, the fact that $D$ is hyperbolic also plays a crucial role).

Comment: The way my text is structured is bothering me.  The mentioning of the hyperbolic nature of $D$ is completely left out until Apendix D or something.

Comment: One last question, this only allows me to conclude that the family of iterates are normal, but not that the iterates converge to $z_0$.

Comment: @emka right. the family of iterates is normal, so there are limits of subsequences. pick one such limit, let's call it $h$: since points near $z_0$ are attracted to it, $h(z)=z_0$ for all $z$ in an open neighborhood of $z_0$. by the identity theorem, $h$ is therefore constant equal to $z_0$ on $D$. since this is true for all limits of subsequences, the total sequence of iterates converges to the constant $z_0$.